# How can I count total data wrong when compare between array with another array?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I count total data wrong when compare between array with another array?

**example input like this.**

```
$data= array('1','2','5','7');
```

**I want to compare the value with this value in variable `$data2` the output of variable `$data2` like this :**

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [kalimat] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [kalimat] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [kalimat] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [kalimat] => 6
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [kalimat] => 7
        )
    )
```

How can I count total wrong data in `$data` where compare with `$data2` ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `array_diff` function?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: No I haven't tried, I will try it now@Dan Hawkins

Comment: It will give you the difference of the 2 arrays. So, you will still need to evaluate the diff. But, this could get you closer.

Comment: thanks very much, I'm still trying with array_diff@Dan Hawkins